# What is the name of the variable $b$ in the equation $F=-bv$?

Tags: friction, terminology, drag

I saw that the equation *F=-bv* is used for the drag force for damped harmonic motion, where *F* is the drag force, *v* is the velocity of the hanging mass.

Question) What is the name for *b* though?

I saw that the value of *b* varies with fluid and dimensions of the object, but still can't find the exact name for that.

Comment: I would suggest that you wait a little more than a few minutes before accepting an answer. Just to see if there are others. People contribute to SE from all around in the world and sometimes the best answer could come from somebody who's  sleeping when you write your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally called the damping coefficient.

Comment: In other context, others call it *drag coefficient*.

Comment: @GiorgioP I always thought that the damping coefficient was a medium only property. Is the drag coefficient the generalisation of that depending on object geometry?

Comment: It is not something  ruled by standards. I would say the the specific choice about the name depends on the physical realization of the damped harmonic oscillator. If the dominant effect comes from viscous forces due to a fluid on the oscillating mass it would be common to see reference to a viscous drag coefficient. In the case of no reference to the exact mechanism of damping it is common to see *damping coefficient*. I cannot exclude other names. In a paper I would always introduce the name accompanied by the formula, to be clear.

Comment: I see. I’ve only ever used $b$ in the context of point particles maybe that’s why. Thank you for the info.